# Ellipse Tangents in 3D

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, 3d, solid-geometry

I know that we can find the tangent of the ellipse in 2D by taking the derivative of the equation defining the ellipse.
But I'm little bit confused about finding the ellipse tangent in 3D. Where the ellipse orientation could be in any direction.
Suppose we have the following information:

- The center of an ellipse in 3D `(cx, cy, cz)`.
- The surface normal of the ellipse `(<v1; v2; v3>)`.
- The major and minor axis.

How can we find the tangent of ellipse at a given point on the ellipse. 
Kindly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathbf c = (cx,cy,cx)$ denote the center, and let $a$ and $b$ denote the semi-axis lengths, or "radii", as usual, and let $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ be two unit vectors in the directions of the major and minor axes respectively. Then the equation of the ellipse can be written as
$$
\mathbf x(\theta) = \mathbf c + (a\cos\theta)\mathbf u +  (b\sin\theta)\mathbf v
$$

Then the first derivative vector is given by
$$
\mathbf x'(\theta) = - (a\sin\theta)\mathbf u +  (b\cos\theta)\mathbf v
$$
This derivative vector gives you the direction of the tangent line at the point $\mathbf x(\theta)$ on the ellipse.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is **θ** ? we are talking about an ellipse in 3D and it's orientation represented in the surface normal vector `<vx; vy; vz>`. I'm wondering how you can find the tangent of rotated ellipse in 3D space without considering the surface normal vector to ellipse?

Comment: What I gave you is the common parametric equation of a 3D ellipse, and $\theta$ is the parameter. It is (roughly) an angle measured in the plane of the two vectors $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the "surface normal" of an ellipse. Maybe you mean the normal vector of the plane in which the ellipse lies. If so, this is not enough information to fully define the orientation of the ellipse. You need two vectors (as I used), or a rotation matrix.

Comment: In astronomy, that $\theta$ parameter is known as the [eccentric anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentric_anomaly).

Comment: Why does $c$ persist in the derivative?

Comment: @AritraDas. That’s a copy/paste error. I fixed it. Thanks.